# how to import different class on different Android sdk version

Tags: android, sdk, import, facebook-android-sdk

here is the example:
PhoneConstants.java is new added on Android 4.2, and i use this class by import it to my custom class:
import com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneConstants;
on this way, my app can not run on phone below android4.2.

my doubt is:
is there any way to import different class on different android version.

Comment: I guess you could always just take the raw file out of the Android source code, but might be a tough job as it's probably linked to dozens of other classes that only run on that Android version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android Support library which "fills in the blanks" from previous Android versions, so you can safely import that class without incurring in runtime problems.

Please see here: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Hope it helps,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), which is specially designed to provide backwards compatibility. However, Support Library doesn't contains only some classes that were ported to work on the older Android version.